# Show a message for a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, django

Here is the javascript part

```
$(function(){
    $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
      $(this).bind('click', function(e){
        $('.select-another-button').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.select-another-button').css('pointer-events', 'auto'); }, 300000);
        e.preventDefault();
        fileBrowser(this);
        return false;
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is the Django method that will send the message

```
@staff_member_required
@csrf_exempt
def send(request, request_id=None):
    req= Request.objects.get(pk=request_id)
    request_folders = req.folder.all_files.all()
    context = []

    for doc in request_folders:
        if doc.meta.state == u'rejected':
            context.append(doc)

    if context:
        ctx = {'request': req}
        EmailFromTemplate('document-refusal', extra_context=ctx)\
            .send_to(req.customer.user)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

Here is the `urls.py` file

```
app_name = 'messaging'
urlpatterns = [
   ...,

    url(r'^send/(?P<request_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        send, name='send'),
]
```

Here is the part of the `.html` file

```
        <a href="#"
       title="{% trans "Send email - rejected file(s)" %}"
       class="btn btn-icon select-another-button"
       data-url="{% url "messaging:send" request_id=object.pk %}">
        <i class="material-icons">assignment_late</i>
        <div class='alert alert-success' id='message'>
            <text>
            The message was sent to the client. Please wait 5 minutes \n before sending the message again.
            </text>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Here is what I've done so far. It's not to the point yet, but I think it doesn't lack a lot to be functional. I have created a button which will send a specific message under certain conditions. Once it is send, I want that the button to be deactivate (i.e. we can't click on click to send a message) for a time of 5 minutes. Furthermore, I want during that time to show a message 'we have already sent the message. Please wait 5 minutes before sending again.' with `bootstrap` or `materialize` box.

It is hard for me to do such thing since I don't have a lot of experience with `Javascript`, `HTML` and `Django`. How could I modify this code in such a way it work? So far the button is well created and it sent the message I want. The problem I have is it doesn't want to wait 5 minutes and I just don't even know how to display the message I want.

The button I have created is that [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTKF.png)

To display the message, could I use `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` in my Django method `send` and reuse it in my the javascript block? Do I have to use JQuery to display such message?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript setTimeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp. 
give timeout as five minutes. And write code to activate button in the callback function.

Comment: setTimeout - This is exactly what I use so far

Comment: it's doubtful... Could you show me how I could display my message with bootstrap?

Comment: initially keep the bootstrap message hidden using display:none. and in the click event change to display: block. And in the callback function of setTimeout make  back to display:none

Comment: Sorry, my experience with js is very basic. I think you'll need to show me a little bit more

Comment: `$(function(){

    $('.select-another-button').each(function(){
      $(this).bind('click', function(e){
          $('#message').show()
          
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#message').hide() }, 300000);
        e.preventDefault();
        fileBrowser(this);
        return false;
      });
    });
  }); `

Comment: ` <div class="alert alert-success" id="message">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>`

Comment: use $('#message').show() and $('#message').hide() to show and hide the bootstrap div with class "alert alert-success"

Comment: Put it in your answer ;)

Comment: Could you just give me an example of what I have to put in show() and hide()

Comment: you dont have put anything. it just show & hide the particular div with id "message".

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="message"> <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action. </div>

$(function(){ $('.select-another-button').each(function(){ $(this).bind('click', function(e){ $('#message').show() setTimeout(function(){ $('#message').hide() }, 300000); e.preventDefault(); fileBrowser(this); return false; }); }); });
```